# Unique Index if the values is not null or empty sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have users table in in users table email can be Null , '' , or a value@gmail.com, now i want to create a Unique Index if email column contains values and ignore both null as well as ''

I know we can create or Not nulls

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_Users_Email] ON [Users] ([Email]) WHERE [Email] IS NOT NULL -- Works
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_Users_Email] ON [Users] ([Email]) WHERE [Email] <> '' -- Works

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_Users_Email] ON [Users] ([Email]) WHERE [Email] IS NOT NULL Or [Email] <> ''; --Not working
```

How can i achieve this with Sql server, Ef core code first approch

Comment: Don't you mean `[Email] <> ''`?

Comment: An empty string is not `Null`, so it would pass your filter. I suspect you mean `WHERE [Email] IS NOT NULL And [Email] <> ''` instead.

Comment: `filter: "[Email] IS NOT NULL And [Email] <> ''")` worked like a charm

Comment: Please only use tags that clearly relate to the question. It's not clear how EF is related.

Comment: You don't even need the `IS NOT NULL` because `<> ''` means that it's not null either

Comment: `[Email] IS NOT NULL Or [Email] <> ''` will always return true if the value isn't `NULL`, including for `''`. If `Email` has the value `''` then `[Email] IS NOT NULL` is `TRUE`, and `TRUE OR FALSE` = `TRUE`.